# Linking appended titles local storage

Tags: javascript, html

I have an editor that allows users to input text and save it under a title name using a prompt.

```
    //Get the title from the user
    var title = prompt("What would you like your title to be?");
    localStorage.setItem(title, editElem.innerHTML);
```

I then assign the different titles into a key called "titles"

```
    //Asigning the titles input by the user to the key "titles"
    titles = localStorage.getItem("titles");

    if (titles == null){
        titles = [];
    }
    else {
        titles = JSON.parse(titles);
    }

    titles.push(title);
    localStorage.setItem("titles",JSON.stringify(titles));
```

Finally, I create text nodes for the titles and append them to a content table (Just a simple div to display their titles)

```
    //Add titles to content table
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Edits saved!";
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("Contentable");
    var content = document.createTextNode(title);
    theDiv.appendChild(content);
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    theDiv.appendChild(br);
```

Also, the text that they input into the editor will also be saved

```
    var editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
    var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
    localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;
```

Now, I'm trying to link the appended titles that show up to their respective content. 
e.g. if they type "Hello world" into the editor and save it as "First", the word "First", which will be stored under title, will show up in the content div. When they click the word "First", the editor will load the text they have input and saved under "First".

Using this example, here's what's stored inside my local storage:

Key:Value

First:Hello world

titles:["First"]

userEdits:Hello world

=================

EDIT:

JS

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
    <!-- Function to save the user's input inside editor1 -->
    var editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#savebtn").click(function() {
        var title = prompt("What would you like your title to be?");
        localStorage.setItem(title, editElem.value);
        titles = localStorage.getItem("titles");

        if (titles == null) {
          titles = [];
        } else {
          titles = JSON.parse(titles);
        }
        titles.push(title);
        localStorage.setItem("titles", JSON.stringify(titles));
        document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Edits saved!";
        var htmlData = "<a onclick=showData('" + title + "')>" + title + "</a><br>";
        $("#Contentable").append(htmlData);
        var userVersion = editElem.value;
        localStorage.setItem("userEdits", userVersion);
        editElem.value = "";
      });
    });

    function showData(txt) {
      editElem.value = localStorage.getItem(txt);
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="Contentable">
        <div id="contentheader">
        <h1><u><center>Content</center></u></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="editor1" contenteditable="true" style="margin-left:30em">
    </div>
    <input id="savebtn" type="button" value="Save Changes"/>
    <div id="update">Click to save your changes made</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following code : [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4uwvcrdc/)

```
var editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#savebtn").click(function() {
    var title = prompt("What would you like your title to be?");
    localStorage.setItem(title, editElem.value);
    titles = localStorage.getItem("titles");

    if (titles == null) {
      titles = [];
    } else {
      titles = JSON.parse(titles);
    }
    titles.push(title);
    localStorage.setItem("titles", JSON.stringify(titles));
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Edits saved!";
    var htmlData = "<a onclick=showData('" + title + "')>" + title + "</a><br>";
    $("#Contentable").append(htmlData);
    var userVersion = editElem.value;
    localStorage.setItem("userEdits", userVersion);
    editElem.value = "";
  });
});

function showData(txt) {
  editElem.value = localStorage.getItem(txt);
}
```

Comment: When I click the save changes button it doesn't work. I've updated my code and added in the html as well just in case you can find an error there.

Comment: I actually copied and pasted your code into a new html file and ran it - same issue; the button doesn't work.

Comment: it works when there is textbox as editor. see my example fiddle and try to make changes accordingly. I hope my fiddle works for you as it works for me

Comment: Your fiddle works, but when I place it in a html file it doesn't.

Comment: you need to make changes in that according to your div and components

Comment: Even when I don't make any changes and directly copy and paste, it doesn't work either. I already tried making a new html file that contains exactly what is in your fiddle.

Comment: Is there a pure javascript alternative?